# mount.cifs vs NFSv3 for data shared between 2 Web servers

Tags: linux, nfs, cifs

When having two RHEL 6 Linux servers separated by a load balancer serving Tomcat and Apache content, if the data is shared between the 2 servers via a network locally-mounted filesystem, does it matter whether this filesystem is CIFS or NFSv3?  Should I expect comparable performance from either?  Are there any pros or cons to one versus the other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a wonderful benchmark estimation available from [here](http://www.hob.de/downloads/NFS_CIFS.pdf). Most of the contents in the above link are just pictures which says it all. However, for reference sake, this is the benchmark for reading a **5 GB** file.[image]

So by the looks of it, for Linux systems it is suggested to use **NFS**.